# move file based on iso8601 date format that is 1 week old

Tags: grep, find, mv, touch

I have a set of backups that run on a cron job every 4 hours (00:00, 04:00...etc). These files are named based on;
`NOW=$(date +%F-%a-%H.%M)-filename` which translates to `2016-10-25-Tue-04.00-filename`.

I would like to copy the most recent file with `Mon-00.00` once a week on a Monday to another folder called `weekly`. I was trying `find . -mtime +0 | grep "Mon-00" | -exec mv /file/path/weekly {} \;`  but I can't figure out how to test it as I haven't created the files yet. Will this work? Or can you advise on how I create dummy files to test it with `touch`?

Comment: Why did you not try it first?

Comment: because the need to move them and change the name format just arose yesterday - a manager has decided! lol

Comment: I meant more of "why did you not run the command first". If you change pattern, e.g. from Mon-00 to test-00 then you should be fine. Anyway your approach will not work, -exec is a flag for find, not a command on itself and you've already used pipe so you're out of find. You can also use multiple flags, so you could do something like `find . -regex "Mon-00.*" -mtime +0 -exec ...`, althought I don't remember find's regex syntax that well, so experiment yourself a bit.

Answer (score 0):

`find . \( -name "*Mon-00*" \) -mtime +6 -exec mv -t weekly {} \;`